# User Editable Table

Tags: php, database, user-input

How would I go about creating a table that is linked to a specific user that can be edited by that user? Basically a user would log in, and they would see a button that took them to a page with a bunch of specifically labeled input boxes. They could put the appropriate data into the boxes and save it. There should also be a drop down menu that contains presets for the data. At first I thought to use a database, but here's the kicker: They need to be able to add and delete input boxes. To recap, the user needs to have their own specific page that allows them to change data in input boxes, as well as add more fields if they require it. This all needs to be stored and linked to their user. How can I do this?

Comment: It would be really great if downvotes weren't left without telling me why this is a bad question. Thanks. -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should realize that in PHP / MySQL. I do not know where you are in your project, if you have already achieved your login pages / sing_up / index ... etc.. but you should start with that. There are good tutorials on the subject, like this one.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/user-membership-with-php

**EDIT:**
To let user edit their info, look at this tutorial:
http://www.webestools.com/scripts_tutorials-code-source-14-members-area-system-in-php-mysql-members-users-system-area-log-sign.html

After, you will have to ajust your actual structure to the one they give.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate you spending your time to point me in the right direction! :)

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it satisfies you!